# Recognizing multiple UILabels tap for UITapGestureRecogniser

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my view load I have two UILabels and I have added same tapGesture for both.If a particular label is tapped then its functionality should be performed.But I m unable to do so ?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  lblEditProfile.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelClicked:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
   [lblEditProfile addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
   [tapGestureRecognizer release];

   lblViewDetails.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelClicked:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

    [lblViewDetails addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [tapGestureRecognizer release];
}

-(IBAction)labelClicked:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGestureRecognizer
{

    currentLabel = (UILabel *)tapGestureRecognizer.view;
    NSLog(@"tap %@",tapGestureRecognizer.view);

    if(currentLabel.text==@"Edit Profile")
    {


        UserProfile *userProfile = [[UserProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserProfile" bundle:nil];
        userProfile.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:userProfile animated:YES];
        [userProfile release];



    }
    else
    {

        ViewDetails *viewDetails = [[ViewDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserAppointments" bundle:nil];
        viewDetails.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController: viewDetails animated:YES];
        [viewDetails release];


    }


}
```

But when I click on EditProfile label it is going to else block.

How can I recognize which Label is clicked and correspondingly perform required action?

Comment: set Tag for each label And Compare as per tagValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check like this:

```
  if(currentLabel == lblEditProfile)
    //code here
  else
     //code here
```

Answer (score 7):

Use Tag format like this. Which will be efficient

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  lblEditProfile.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  lblEditProfile.tag = 1;
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelClicked:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
   [lblEditProfile addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
   [tapGestureRecognizer release];

   lblViewDetails.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   lblViewDetails.tag = 2;
  tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelClicked:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

    [lblViewDetails addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [tapGestureRecognizer release];
}

-(IBAction)labelClicked:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGestureRecognizer
{

    currentLabel = (UILabel *)tapGestureRecognizer.view;
    NSLog(@"tap %d",tapGestureRecognizer.tag);

    if(currentLabel.tag == 1)
    {


        UserProfile *userProfile = [[UserProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserProfile" bundle:nil];
        userProfile.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:userProfile animated:YES];
        [userProfile release];



    }
    else if(currentLabel.tag == 2)
    {

        ViewDetails *viewDetails = [[ViewDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserAppointments" bundle:nil];
        viewDetails.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController: viewDetails animated:YES];
        [viewDetails release];


    }


}
```

Comment: This part: -(IBAction)labelClicked:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGestureRecognizer
{currentLabel = (UILabel *)tapGestureRecognizer.view; helped me in getting the label being touched on. Thanks!