# multiple UILabels tap for same UITapGestureRecogniser Not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to add same UITapGestureRecognizer to multiple views as

```
  var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "selectOptionsForRating:")
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        serviceLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        pickUpTimeLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        drivingLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        communicateLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        bikeConditionLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        dropOffLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        serviceLbl.tag = Service
        pickUpTimeLbl.tag = PickUpTime
        drivingLbl.tag = Driving
        communicateLbl.tag = Communicate
        bikeConditionLbl.tag = BikeCondition
        dropOffLbl.tag = DropOff


    }

    func selectOptionsForRating(tapsender:UITapGestureRecognizer){

        var sender = tapsender.view

        if sender!.tag == Service {
             println("tap gesture is working fine ")

        }else if sender!.tag == PickUpTime {
            println("tap gesture is working fine ")

        }else if sender!.tag == Driving {
            println("tap gesture is working fine ")

        }else if sender!.tag == Communicate {
            println("tap gesture is working fine ")

        }else if sender!.tag == BikeCondition {
            println("tap gesture is working fine ")

        }else if sender!.tag == DropOff {
            println("tap gesture is working fine ")

        }
```

[Recognizing multiple UILabels tap for UITapGestureRecogniser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081466/recognizing-multiple-uilabels-tap-for-uitapgesturerecogniser) This link shows me how to add same gesture recognizer to multiple views,but it doesnot works..Can't i add same gesture recognizer to multiple views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can not do it with one Gesture but you can add different gesture for all and access same method for all. consider below code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var serviceLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickUpTimeLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var drivingLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var communicateLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bikeConditionLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var dropOffLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var tapGestureForserviceLbl = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "selectOptionsForRating:")
        var tapGestureForpickUpTimeLbl = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "selectOptionsForRating:")
        var tapGestureFordrivingLbl = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "selectOptionsForRating:")
        var tapGestureForcommunicateLbl = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "selectOptionsForRating:")
        var tapGestureForbikeConditionLbl = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "selectOptionsForRating:")
        var tapGestureFordropOffLbl = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "selectOptionsForRating:")

        tapGestureForserviceLbl.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureForpickUpTimeLbl.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureFordrivingLbl.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureForcommunicateLbl.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureForbikeConditionLbl.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureFordropOffLbl.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        serviceLbl.userInteractionEnabled = true
        pickUpTimeLbl.userInteractionEnabled = true
        drivingLbl.userInteractionEnabled = true
        communicateLbl.userInteractionEnabled = true
        bikeConditionLbl.userInteractionEnabled = true
        dropOffLbl.userInteractionEnabled = true

        serviceLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureForserviceLbl)
        pickUpTimeLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureForpickUpTimeLbl)
        drivingLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureFordrivingLbl)
        communicateLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureForcommunicateLbl)
        bikeConditionLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureForbikeConditionLbl)
        dropOffLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureFordropOffLbl)

        serviceLbl.tag = 1
        pickUpTimeLbl.tag = 2
        drivingLbl.tag = 3
        communicateLbl.tag = 4
        bikeConditionLbl.tag = 5
        dropOffLbl.tag = 6
    }

    func selectOptionsForRating(tapsender:UITapGestureRecognizer){

        var sender = tapsender.view!.tag

        switch sender {
        case 1 :
            println("tap gesture is working fine 1")
        case 2 :
            println("tap gesture is working fine 2")
        case 3 :
            println("tap gesture is working fine 3")
        case 4 :
            println("tap gesture is working fine 4")
        case 5 :
            println("tap gesture is working fine 5")
        case 6 :
            println("tap gesture is working fine 6")
        default :
            println("tap gesture can not find view")
        }
    }
}
```

For more Information you can refer this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html).

Hope It will help you.

Comment: yeah..i know i can do it making new instance of gesture recognizer..but why i cant with the one only?

Comment: Your answer is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html

Comment: thanks for the link...i was looking the same..so ,is it due to the hit tested method..so the tapgesture recognizer added to many views gets puzzled to find the responder?

Answer (score 0):

For using UITapGestureRecognizer on Uilabel ... you must Set `label.userInteractionEnabled = true` . just add this line to viewWillAppear and it will Work just Fine.

Comment: actually it is working fine if there is only one label...i want the same gesture recognizer work when there are multiple views..in my case label

Comment: OP's question is regarding multiple UILabels not working on same TapRecognizer.